# Why is my .git directory being served by nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I was recently informed by a security tool that our website is serving files from the .git directory (ouch!)

But why is nginx still serving this dir with the following deny statement? We have restarted our nginx service.

```
server {
    if ($host = ...) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name ...;
    return 301 https://...$request_uri;


}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  ...;

    root   /var/sites/.../public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/.../fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/.../privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location ~ /\. { # why is this not working?
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php74/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

We used a common deny statement found online, starting nginx, without any luck.

Comment: Are there any other `server` blocks in your configuration? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: @RichardSmith a few but this domain is only managed by this config file, they are included with a `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` statement

Comment: It was a browser caching issue, sorry to bother you guys...